# Check whether a polyhedron is empty or not

Tags: convex-optimization, polyhedra

I have a polyhedron of the form 
$$ P=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \mathbf{Ax}\leq\mathbf{b}\}.$$
This polyhedron is an intersection of two other polyhedra, and I want to know if the intersection exists or not, i.e. how can I check if this polyhedron is an empty set or not? I am looking for an algorithm that is computationally inexpensive.

In my problem, I have more inequalities than the dimension $\mathbf{x}$, so the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a tall matrix.

I have already done some research, and I think that maybe the Farka's lemma is helpful, but I have not yet found a proper solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Farkas' Lemma. One of its variants is

> Either the system $Ax\leq b$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a solution, or the system $A^Ty=0$, $b^Ty<0$ for $y\geq 0$ has a solution.

and you can use any linear programming software to solve the latter system.

Comment: To add on to this, here is a trick that might be helpful while checking the condition using a linear program (LP) solver. LP solvers don't support strict inequalities, which you can circumvent by letting them solve the following LP.

\begin{align*}
&\text{max } \epsilon \\
&\text{s.t. } \epsilon \geq 0, y \geq 0,\\
&\hspace{1.25em}A^Ty = 0, \\
&\hspace{1.25em}b^Ty - \epsilon \leq 0
\end{align*}

If this LP is infeasible or the solution is $\epsilon^\ast = 0$, the original polyhedron is empty. Otherwise, it is not.